# Silverlight : Add a visual transition between the states visible and invisible

Tags: silverlight, visibility, transition

I would like to add a visual effect (such as fade in, fade out) on a control which the Visibility can change.

I have no idea where to start to do it. I've read a bit about the VisualStateManager and VisualTransform but I still don't know if it's possible and what to do. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

What you want is possible.

You need a `VisualStateManager` which defines a `ShowState` and a `HideState`. These in turn define a `Storyboard` which controls the visibility.

You then call

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(uiElement, "ShowState", true);
```

on your element to send into the "ShowState" with animation. Replacing the state name with "HideState" will hide the element.

The XAML we use for the `VisualStateManager` is below. It animates the opacity as well so there is a fade in/fade out.

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01"
                                              Value="1" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="HideState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01"
                                              Value="0" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**NOTE** The `KeyTime` values on these may need tweaking for your application. Looking at these again I see that the "HideState" times are both 0, which may not give you the effect you want. AnthonyWJones may well have found an error in our application!

Comment: +1 but are you sure the KeyTime on the DiscreteObjectKeyFrames is correct?

Comment: @Anthony - Maybe not now you come to mention it. The code *appears* to work in our application but I've not double checked it works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't fade as expected.  You can lose the BeginTime and Duration properties and set all the KeyTime properties to 1 second.  then you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Steph D. - I know, @AnthonyWJones pointed them out. I made a change, but I still don't think it's perfect. It should, however, give you something to work with. Once I get our code working properly I'll update the answer.

Comment: okay (sorry i put my comment on the root of the thread because of the length :-))